# How do you declare styles in a way where the global style can be overriden?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got the following scenario

```
custom control library 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}" x:Key="Default"> ... </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}"> ... </Style>
application which references custom control library
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource Default}"> ... </Style>
```

for some reason the styles i am specifying in my app.xaml seem to have no effect. Could it be that the App.xaml is loaded prior to foreign generic.xaml contents? And if so - How does one fix that so global style overrides do work.

Comment: Where and how are you defining and merging your styles? You need to apply the styles in the correct order.

Comment: custom control library defines its styles in Themes/Generic.xaml. application does not reference the Generic.xaml but maintains its own Merged ResourceDictionary (Where i in turn reference a Styles.xaml). Are you saying that you are sure that this should technically work, but is an issue of me setting things up wrong?

Comment: Overriding a Style is certainly possible.

Comment: @mm8 Yes, but you are certain it also works for global styles? Because that is what i seem to get working here.

Comment: What are "global styles"?

Comment: @mm8 styles without x:Key, which are the default styles for any control they handle. That's the only styles i am having an issue here with overriding

Comment: Please provide an example of your issue instead of posting comments.